# Is it the norm for hotels not to provide washing service for undergarments in India?

Tags: india, clothing

A strange event happened while I was travelled to Kerela (*), I asked the hotels to take care of my laundry , they said sure they'd do the clothes except the inner garments. I asked why they refused the inner garments, the reason given was that it is 'unhygienic'. I was a bit taken aback, then comes the question here:

Is it the norm here? Would travellers have to wash their own inner wear?

---

*: I was actually born here, but I had been living outside India for quite a while now.

Comment: In India, you typically don't wash your underwear in the washing machine.What is the star rating of the hotel you stayed? is it an independent hotel or belongs to a chain of hotels?

Comment: @AAk google reviews say it is 4.8, it seems to be a singleton

Comment: I think Aak means the standard of service.  Is it a 3-star hotel, or a 4-star hotel, or what?  These star rating systems set certain minimum levels of service in order to obtain a certain number of stars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_rating

Comment: How do I identify the standard of service of a hotel @Kyralessa

Comment: I have to ask - how do you wash your underwear in India?

Comment: @DJClayworth a significant part, imo around 50-60% don't have washing machines. They wash all their clothes using detergent powder in a bucket. To be specific about underwear, people generally take a bath wearing one. After getting done with the bath, they just wash it in a bucket after applying detergent soap.

Comment: Does the hotel have a laundry rate list? If undergarments are on it the hotel will accept them which is usually the case with larger/luxury hotels.

Comment: I don't think so,  but to be clear, they agreed to wash my other clothing @RedBaron

Comment: I haven't stayed in enough hotels in India to be able to answer the general case, but some certainly do.  I also on that trip washed some essential clothes (i.e. underwear, socks, etc.)  in the sink, as that fitted in better with our itinerary.  I've done this on most long trips in many countries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely not true. I am a frequent traveller and I usually stay at IHG group hotels (Holiday Inn, Crown Plaza, etc.).

They do accept underwear for laundry / dry cleaning. The rates are insane but they do accept contrary to your experience.

Comment: Years ago I had a lot of clothes washed by a hotel (including underwear).  It would have been cheaper to go out and buy all new clothes

Comment: Yup, for sure it's true.